# How to get updated React Context with static variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have **ClientContext** with default value:

```
export const defaultContext = {
    test: "Hello"
};

export const UserApplicationContext = React.createContext(defaultContext);
```

And then in my child component I am updating this value:

```
    contextDefaultData = this.context,
    contextData = {
        ...contextDefaultData,
        test: "New"
        }
    };

<UserApplicationContext.Provider value={contextData}>
    <App/>
</UserApplicationContext.Provider>
```

Now, question: In **App** I can access updated value via **UserApplicationContext.Consumer** component **but I can't** access updated value via static like this:

```
import UserApplicationContext from './UserApplicationContext'
static contextType = UserApplicationContext
```

So, `this.context` will point to default value, but not to updated one.
How may I access updated value without exporting new Context?
Thanks!

Comment: In the code you posted the context isn't updated. Do you mean that you receive defaultContext value but not contextData?

Comment: @estus Yes. I want to somehow get contextData outside render() {} in App component.

Comment: Outside `render` - where exactly? The question doesn't contain the entire component you have problems with. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that contains all relevant code, so it could be made workable. It's like the answer says. contextType causes a rerender of the component when new context value is received. So the value should be available in `render` and `componentDidUpdate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's a limitation of the context api?

In order to access the most recent version of the context, you have to be inside of a component that is rendered inside of the provider's component tree and you either have to consume the context like `<UserApplicationContext.Consumer>` or if you wanna use hooks/functional components, you can do it in a nicer way like `const mostRecentContext = useContext(UserApplicationContext)`.

If you try to import the context like that and access it without a consuming it via a `.Consumer` or the `useContext` hook, it will always be whatever the value use passed to `React.createContext()`.